# After upgrade to qt 5.5.0 I got warning for QML imports

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.4, qt5.5

I just upgraded from 5.4.1 to 5.5.0 today. But when I build my android project I get these lines of warning in compile output:

```
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: HelperWidgets
```

What is this? My project compiles without any warnings in the previous version.

Comment: Which target platform? A quick grep through Qt shows this only comes up with `androiddeployqt`.

Comment: Which window in Qt Creator do the errors show up in? Compile Output or General Messages? Is it when you build or does it only happen when you deploy?

Comment: Hello there. When I build the android application Compile output shows these warnings.

Comment: So no deploying to your device is done, and these warnings still show up?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, build causes this warning

Comment: Have you tried wiping your build directory and rebuilding? Does `qml/QtQuick/Extras` exist in your Qt installation?

Comment: @Mitch Yes it does exist. And I tried clean, rebuild and I also manually deleted the build directory but no difference!

Comment: Then I don't know. You're probably better off creating a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

The Qt project has a [bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa) where you should have searched for your issue.

[This](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47389) bug was reported a few days before your post here.

My conclusion: This issue is a bug in at least Qt 5.5.0 and 5.5.1.

Edit: The issue is still there with Qt 5.9. I never had any real problem here, and the fact that the priority in the issue trakcer is P3 indicates that this is nothing else but an incorrect warning which can simply be ignored.

Comment: Do you have another useful tip? That appears to be an issue in 5.6 (for me as well) surely if this was a bigger with Qt there would be more noise about it.